# collection name has been set as null after aggregate

Tags: php, mongodb, match

I try to connect to mongodb same as below

```
$mongo = new \MongoDB\Client();
$db = $mongo->selectCollection("tourism","users");
```

It's ok when i use $db variable to find or insert or another functions(same as below code)

```
object(MongoDB\Driver\Cursor)[66]
public 'database' => string 'tourism' (length=7)
public 'collection' => string 'users' (length=5)
```

But when i try to use aggregate, collection name has been set as null.

```
object(MongoDB\Driver\Cursor)[66]
public 'database' => string 'tourism' (length=7)
public 'collection' => null
```

And its my complete code in PHP

```
$mongo = new \MongoDB\Client();
$db = $mongo->selectCollection("tourism","users");
$ops = [['$match'=>['key'=>'09216604502']]];
$results = $db->aggregate($ops);
exit(var_dump($results));
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you are running, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: post edited ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that problem.
While using aggregate collection name should be null and it will fill in the pipeline variable.

after execute aggregate command we should convert it to array with below code in PHP

```
$db = $mongo->selectCollection("tourism","languages");
$ops = [['$match'=>['code'=>'fa']]];
$results = $db->aggregate($ops);
$results = current($results->toArray());
```